# BMW 318d 2006 E90 - DPF Filter?

Tags: bmw, diesel, diesel-particulate-filter

I have a BMW 318d 2006, and it has been acting weird for a couple of days now, I have researched that some of the 318d have DPF filters and some Don't, my problem is where I drive to work 200km there and back.. sometimes it feels like the car is losing power for a sec and then its back to normal and again loses power for a sec and back to normal, that does not happen all the time just sometimes, Does this sound like an issue with DPF?

EDIT- by losing power I mean i feels like it's pulling back kind of light breaking feeling.

Comment: That may not be the DPF, but it could be the EGR. Have you checked for any error codes? That would be a good first step.

Comment: I haven't checked for any error code, I can't actually leave my car at a mechanic workshop as I leave in the morning come back in the evening everyday, weekends they are booked out. The earliest date is in 3 weeks. I dont have a computer to check for error codes myself, I can probably change the DPF or EGR Myself as my father is a retired mechanic

Comment: What happened in the end? Was it the EGR valve?

Comment: @DimitarNikovski It was the Abs sensor, The end of it was scratched.